# MongoDb push only if property not already in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to update a nested array in a document only if the array does not already include the item like so:

```
await userCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: ObjectId('616acc597ebda90ca6ffee21') },
    {
      'devices': {
        $push: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $in: [req.body.serial, '$devices']
            },
            then: '$devices',
            else: { serial: req.body.serial, data: [] }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { returnOriginal: false },
    (err, _) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400);
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json(user.value);
      }
    }
  );
```

This is my user object:

```
{
    "_id": "616acc597ebda90ca6ffee21",
    "username": "test@test.com",
    "displayName": "Test",
    "devices": [
      {
        "serial": "865674036421275",
        "data": [
          {
            "timestamp": "2021-10-16T12:36:35.799Z"
          },
          {            
            "timestamp": "2021-10-16T12:41:33.633Z"
          },
          {           
            "timestamp": "2021-10-16T12:52:03.055Z"
          }
        ]
      },
      
    ],
    "hashedPassword": "R5vt3vY7vEvTHvhC7YGNOWuIjBUQGLqsd92QGE06tjU=",
    "salt": "6RS0OVIFboCkIEPHdZmTcQ==",
    "dateCreated": "2021-10-16T12:58:00.294Z"
  }
```

How will I check if serial is already in devices? Also, is it possible to throw an error if it already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query

- find to update only documents that dont have this serial
  (with `eq/ne` query operators, we can do arrays=value, if array has the value its true)
- replace the `"000"` with the serial you want to add
- push in the end
- updateOne will return the result, and you can see if update is done or not, see your driver method details.

*it will be fast, and you dont need an index on `devices.serial`
because it selects a specific document already with the `_id` match

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ToxETCqyXWX)

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("616acc597ebda90ca6ffee21"),
  "devices.serial": {
    "$ne": "000"
  }
},
{
  "$push": {
    "devices": {
      "serial": "000",
      "data": []
    }
  }
})
```

We cant mix update operators with aggregate operators.
`$cond` is aggregate operator, it cant be mixed with `$push` update operator. (aggregate `$push` is for group, cant add to an array)

We can do the update with update pipeline, but here a normal update is simpler.

Comment: All the answers helped me but this one was the most elaborate

Answer (score 3):

There's an update operator called `addToSet`
check it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Raw Query

```
db.userCollection.updateOne({
    _id: ObjectId('616acc597ebda90ca6ffee21'), // Object Id, make sure It is Object Id only else match just string version
    "devices.serial": {$ne: "SerialNeedToMatch" }
}, {
    $push: {
        "devices": {
            serial: '111' // or complete object 
        }
    }
})
```